# Commandline app built with visual studio 9 does not take *.NEF as input while same app built with gcc does - why?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, gcc

I built dcraw.c (http://www.cybercom.net/~dcoffin/dcraw/dcraw.c) as a windows command line application with cygwin / gcc before. Today I built it with visual studio 2008 as that allows including the libraries LIBJPEG and LCMS into the exe file and does not require the cygwin1.dll either. Also the VC built version seems to be faster. So much for the prelude.

The actual question is this: When I use the final application say as in dcraw -T -4 *.NEF 
The cygwin / gcc built version will process all NEF files in my directory while the visual studio built one says: *.NEF: Invalid argument

I have no idea why that is and am looking for a way to fix this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: processing single files works the same with either version of course

Comment: That's the *nix shell expanding wildcards for file names. It has nothing to do with the compiler.

Comment: @Bo in this case it's not both programs are windows programs and both are run from the same shell - the windows cmd prompt.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need to add [`setargv.obj`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bch7bkk.aspx) to be linked in.  It will expand the wildcards.  If you are using the command line (cl.exe), you can just specify it on the command line:

```
cl yourfile.c /link setargv.obj
```

In a Visual Studio project, you can add it to the Additional Dependencies field in the Linker Input options in the project properties.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in this direction. I tried adding it to the additional dependencies tab but so far it didn't work out. So I'll google some more for setargv.obj

Comment: I think I included the setargv.obj correctly - just like you said but it doesn't work. Does the int CLASS main (int argc, const char **argv) need to be changed for this to work out? it's line 8613 in dcraw.c linked to above.

Comment: I had this problem recently, but simply including `setargv.obj` in the Linker's "Additional Dependencies" field was enough to get it to work for me.  I did not have to change the arguments to main.  Not sure what's different in your case (except I was using VC2005)

Comment: @Qwerty:  I just now tried it in VS2009 (which I *think* is VS9 ... I have a hard time remembering the versions) and it worked.  I looked at that source file a bit and don't see anything obvious that should cause a problem.  It appears that CLASS is an empty definition.  I tried the exact same declaration in my little test app and it all worked as expected.  So I'm stumped.  Look in the VS linker properties under the "Command Line".  Does setargv.obj show up there in front of a bunch of .lib files?

Comment: @Qwerty:  Just as a sanity check, you might create a brand new visual studio C console app with "int i; for (i=0;i<argc;i++)printf("%s\n", argv[i]);" as the body of main and see if it works.

Comment: A note for anyone who also has trouble with this solution: Any other statically linked projects ALSO need to have linked `setargv.obj`/`wsetargv.obj`, or the advanced version won't be used for the command line project. The OP mentions linking LIBJPEG and LCMS into the exe, so this was probably the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running both builds from the same type of command interpreter?  On Unix systems, the shell expands wildcards; Windows `cmd.exe` doesn't, leaving it to the program to do if necessary.  If you're running one build from `cmd` and the other from Cygwin's `bash`, that could explain the different behaviors.

Comment: no both are being run from a normal windows command window - invoked by the same *.bat file actually.