# How to expand "*.*" into a list of files? (Windows console C)

Tags: console-application, fopen

I've got a Visual C++ console application which parses one or more files. To parse all `N` `.txt` files I'd like to call it with `program.exe *.txt` and have that expanded into a list in `argv[1]` to `argv[N]`. Instead, I see `*.txt` in `argv[1]`.

Thanks,

Borge

Comment: May be start here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/17w5ykft.aspx. There's a link to wildcard expansion as well.

Comment: @mbratch you missed the link by one. it's http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1w828yy.aspx (yours heads to escaping)

Comment: Thanks! And here are instrucitons on setting it up in the editor: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5346456/commandline-app-built-with-visual-studio-9-does-not-take-nef-as-input-while-sa